# In Prometheus,how to use comparison operators with range vectors？

Tags: prometheus, promql

prometheus has a function [count_over_time()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) to get "the count of all values in the specified interval".

but I want some of the values and not all of them.

like below：

```
count_over_time(up)[1h] == 0
```

prometheus does not support this and will report an error：
`Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:20: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors`.

Or, is there a way to implement the [count_ne_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_ne_over_time) function in MetricsQL in promQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/),
Prometheus doesn't provide [count_ne_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_ne_over_time) function. But you can use the following trick if you need calculating the number of raw samples with zero values over the previous hour for `up` metric in Prometheus:

```
(1 - avg_over_time(up[1h]))
  *
count_over_time(up[1h])
```

This is equivalent to the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query:

```
count_eq_over_time(up[1h], 0)
```

Note that this trick works only if the `up` metric contains 1 and 0 discrete values. If the `up` metric contains other values than 0 and 1, then the PromQL trick above won't return the expected results.